# Claúsula ORDER BY no funciona

Tags: sql

A partir de la siguiente consulta, obtengo una lisa de resultados que NO están ordenados como sabría esperar. He buscado información pero no he encontrado dónde está el error. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT pcbox.codigo, pcbox.nombre, pcbox.precio, pcbox.enlace as enlace, 
       pccomponentes.referencia_fabricante, pccomponentes.precio as 
       precioPccomp, pccomponentes.enlace as enlacePccomp FROM 
       pcbox,pccomponentes WHERE ( pccomponentes.familia = 'Tarjetas 
       Gráficas' AND pcbox.referencia_fabricante = 
       pccomponentes.referencia_fabricante) AND ( (pcbox.nombre LIKE 
       '%gigabyte%') OR (pcbox.nombre LIKE '%asus%')) 
       ORDER BY pccomponentes.precio
```

Los parámetros de búsqueda se generan en función de la entrada de datos del usuario, esto es simplemente un ejemplo.

Gracias de antemano.

EDITO: Los resultados que arroja son los esperados, salvo por el hecho de no estar ordenados. La columna de precio, en ambas tablas, es de tipo double, no varchar, así que el fallo no reside ahí.

Comment: Que resultado te da? Cual esperabas? Te da algún error en consola?

Comment: Si no lo ordenas te da algún error? Consigues mostrar algún resultado? La sentencia no la acabas en `;` aunque dependiendo del `SGBD` podría no influir.

Comment: Deberías de especificar mas la pregunta, como los resultados que has obtenido

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Esa consulta traerá los registros ordenados por la columna `pccomponentes.precio` si no es lo que esperas puede que esa columna sea un `VARCHAR` o algo así, no una columna numérica.

Comment: Pregunta tonta de la mañana! no debería relacionar igual los id de las dos tablas? relacionarlas? algo como **WHERE pcbox,id=occomponentes.pcbox_id** o un **JOIN**. Porque fuera de eso tampoco le veo algún problema en la consulta

Comment: Podrías agregar unas cuantas filas del resultado que te arroja?

Answer (score -1):

tal vez funcione asi:

```
 
SELECT pb.codigo, pb.nombre, pb.precio, pb.enlace as enlace, 
       pc.referencia_fabricante, pc.precio as 
       precioPccomp, pc.enlace as enlacePccomp 
FROM pcbox as pb

inner join  pccomponentes as pc on pb.referencia_fabricante = pc.referencia_fabricante      

WHERE pc.familia = 'Tarjetas Gráficas' AND ((pb.nombre LIKE '%gigabyte%') OR (pb.nombre LIKE '%asus%')) 

ORDER BY pc.precio
```